# How to see absolute values instead of percents on Events graphs?

Tags: google-fabric

I use custom events for tracking statistics about some deprecated modules are used by users. And I`ll want to remove migrations from deprecated module to a new one when amount of usages will be lower a "waterline".

So, it is not enough convenient to track it via clicking on a date on a graph and check amount of events at the date. Could I somehow switch a type of values on a graph to absolute values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here. For the graphs, we will either show the percentage if the custom attribute is a string or the 25th, median and 75th percentiles if the custom attribute is a number. However, the top 10 custom attribute count will be present below the graph.

Comment: I saw values below a graph, but I wanna see dynamically changes on a graph for several days. But now if an event has a single attribute, on a graph I see 100% for each day - just horizontally line...

Comment: Yes, that's currently what I would expect. Apologies if I'm misunderstanding your need.

Comment: So, could I somehow to get what I need? =)

One more time: I need to see dynamically changes of values (not percents) on a graph (not below it) as a broken line. Even an event has just one attribute.

Comment: Not currently :/